# How to call for the system console in Java?

Tags: java, console

I made a console-based Java application but every time I try to start the .jar file by clicking on it the program seems to be running but there is no console displayed. Is there specific code I must write in order to call for the system console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to bring up a Java console window in Win XP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385678/is-it-possible-to-bring-up-a-java-console-window-in-win-xp)

Comment: By default java uses javaw.exe to run jar files, instead of java.exe, that's why you don't get a console window when running a jar.

Answer (score 3):

Can you start the console first , change directory to where your jar file is and then run java -jar yiurjarfilename ?

Comment: he wants that he double clik his jar and system consol like in windows cmd propmt popup and run his app

Answer (score 1):

The OS takes care of displaying console output. There is no code that you can write within Java to display or hide the "console" (because within Java, there's only standard output & error streams that you write to).

Windows usually leaves the console open after your program exits, but there might be a setting within the Java Runtime Environment that configures that behavior.

Comment: No, there's two ways to run Java in Windows. See the answer to the question of which this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the hint: So there is no setting within the JRE to configure the console-behavior, Windows rather brings up the console when Java is invoked via `javaw.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

gcivil is right, you can see the results in console only if you start from console, if you are in windows you can open the command line Super + R and type cmd, then press enter (Super is the one with the Windows icon)

there you can type : java -jar "absolute path to your file" (don't forget the quotes)

another way is create a .bat file next to the .jar one, the bat file should contain 
java -jar filename.jar

you don't need the quotes nor absolute path since it is next to the .bat file now you can `double click that instead of the .jar`

Once the app is terminated it will close the console, if you need to see what is next you have to add pause

```
java -jar filename.jar
pause
```